# SgmlLinkExtractor not displaying results or following link

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, sgml

I am having problems fully understanding how SGML Link Extractor works. When making a crawler with Scrapy, I can successfully extract data from links using specific URLS. The problem is using Rules to follow a next page link in a particular URL.

I think the problem lies in the `allow()` attribute. When the Rule is added to the code, the results do not display in the command line and the link to the next page is not followed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code...

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule

from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

class AllGigsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "allGigs"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.allgigs.co.uk/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/clubbing-1.html",
        "http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/festivals-1.html",
        "http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/comedy-1.html",
        "http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/theatre_and_opera-1.html",
        "http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/dance_and_ballet-1.html"
    ]    
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="more"]',)), callback="parse_me", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_me(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        infos = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="entry vevent"]')
        items = []
        for info in infos:
            item = TutorialItem()
            item ['artist'] = hxs.xpath('//span[@class="summary"]//text()').extract()
            item ['date'] = hxs.xpath('//abbr[@class="dtstart dtend"]//text()').extract()
            item ['endDate'] = hxs.xpath('//abbr[@class="dtend"]//text()').extract()            
            item ['startDate'] = hxs.xpath('//abbr[@class="dtstart"]//text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
        print items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `restrict_xpaths` - it should point to a block where a link extractor should look for links. Don't specify `allow` at all:

```
rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="more"]'), 
         callback="parse_me", 
         follow=True),
]
```

And you need to fix your `allowed_domains`:

```
allowed_domains = ["www.allgigs.co.uk"]
```

Also note that the `print items` in the `parse_me()` callback is not reachable since it lies after the `return` statement. And, in the loop, you should not apply XPath expression using `hxs`, the expressions should be used in the `info` context. And you can simplify the `parse_me()`:

```
def parse_me(self, response):
    for info in response.xpath('//div[@class="entry vevent"]'):
        item = TutorialItem()
        item['artist'] = info.xpath('.//span[@class="summary"]//text()').extract()
        item['date'] = info.xpath('.//abbr[@class="dtstart dtend"]//text()').extract()
        item['endDate'] = info.xpath('.//abbr[@class="dtend"]//text()').extract()            
        item['startDate'] = info.xpath('.//abbr[@class="dtstart"]//text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your response but i still receive no results in the command line. It also still only scrapes the initial URL. Appreciate your help a lot

Comment: @DanielParkin updated the answer, it was just an `allowed_domains` problem.

Comment: You sir are a blooming legend. Could i maybe ask why this needs to be in this format? Thankyou so much!

Comment: @DanielParkin yeah, it should be a domain string, not a URL..this is a common issue for a lot of users starting with Scrapy.